# Why matlab does not understand * in the names of files?

Tags: string, file, matlab, dir

I tried to use:

```
dir('dirname\*')
```

and it did not work. It started to work after I started to use:

```
dir('dirname\m*')
```

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matlab does understand wildcards `*`, but in the way you unluckiliy tried to adhere to Windows cmd path conventions, you entered the string `\*`, which is a literal asterisk (due to the escaping backslash).

A workaround, or the preferred way to specify paths on all platforms, is using a forward slash `/` as a directory seperator.

```
dir('dirname/*')
```

This also explains why adding the m after the backslash "fixed" the issue; the asterisk was no longer a literal asterisk, but allowed to be interpreted as a wildcard character.

EDIT: [Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) explicitely says the wildcard character is allowed and works as expected (see my explanation above).

Answer (score 0):

What is your OS ? Here on Windows, the first line works well. However, the "*" is maybe considered by Matlab as a literal "*". What happens with `dir('dirname/*')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide the full path, like dir('c:\dirname*.m'),
and make sure the folder 'dirname' exists.