# How to tell matlab to search through several subfolder?

Tags: matlab

I want matlab to search through several (sub)folders in my folder. I have a folder named "myfolder" containing:

```
myfolder1
myfolder2 
myfolder3 ect.
```

In myfolder1, myfolder2, myfolder3 ect. I have files that I want matlab to read and use it in a function.

So my script so far is:

```
list= dir('/home/myfolder/*BDF*')
for i=1:length(list)
function_plot(list)
end
```

But the problem here is that matlab only search in myfolder folder not in the myfolder1, myfolder2 ect. Someone know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download [this File Exchange function](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19550-recursive-directory-listing) from Mathworks called `rdir`. It does exactly what you want, recursively going into subdirectories and returning the results. It acts as an extension to Matlab's native `dir`.

In your example, you would simply use

```
list = rdir('/home/myfolder/*BDF*');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MATLAB R2017a or newer, you can use the [`**` wildcard to perform a recursive search](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html#bvd_n8a).

```
list = dir('/home/myfolder/**/*BDF*');

% Convert to full file paths
files = fullfile(list.folder, list.name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean to replace `function_plot` with [`fplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html)? If so, I suspect that you can figure out how to use it with the documentation available for it.

If you are storing all your folders in the "home" folder, just make the string `dir('/home/*BDF*')`.

It is good that you are using forward slashes, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337846/why-matlab-does-not-understand-in-the-names-of-files) help topic explains.

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all, which specifically states that the OP wants to access files within sub-directories - you've talked about random other bits of the question?

Comment: Read the question again, he states that `"myfolder"` contains `myfolder1, myfolder2, myfolder3, etc.`. He does not specify what you are alluding to is sub-directories within sub-directories, whereas I have understood it that the list of files are all within that one sub-directory. Before giving a down-vote, you should read the question thoroughly. If you are unsure or think I may have made a mistake, please let me know so I can edit the answer. You have not contributed that way.

Comment: Also, if I am wrong in understanding the question, I will delete the answer and let someone else take care of it.